# Use Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and remove others

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)
>   [How do I get “ruby” to do what “ruby1.9.1” does?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56391/how-do-i-get-ruby-to-do-what-ruby1-9-1-does)

I installed ruby 1.9.3-p125 with `rvm`.  `rvm list` yields

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]
```

`rvm use 1.9.3-p125` yields

```
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
Running /usr/share/ruby-rvm/hooks/after_use
```

However, `ruby --version` is `ruby 1.8.7`, (`which ruby` is `/usr/bin/ruby`).

I also have two executables: `ruby1.8` and `ruby1.9.1`, but nothing called `ruby1.9.3` is on the path.

How do I actually get `ruby` to run `ruby1.9.3` (or at the very least, how do I run it at all).

Once I can do that, I'd also like to uninstall the other ruby versions since they're just taking up space.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/187888/44179

Comment: You can use the alternatives system to set which installed version of Ruby the `ruby` command invokes. [The answers here explain how.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56391/how-do-i-get-ruby-to-do-what-ruby1-9-1-does)

Answer (score 0):

These are used to remove  applications:

```
sudo apt-get remove <application>
sudo apt-get remove <application>*

sudo apt-get remove --purge <application>
sudo apt-get remove --purge <application>*

sudo apt-get purge <application>
sudo apt-get purge <application>*
```

Then install reinstall the specific version you wanted.